# How to connect Propel ORM with a Informix database

Tags: php, pdo, orm, informix, propel

I need to use a Informix database with Propel ORM, but I don't find any way to make it.

I find only PDO connections as these:

```
$bd = new PDO("informix:host=host.domain.com; service=9800;
    database=my_db; server=ids_server; protocol=onsoctcp;
    EnableScrollableCursors=1", "my_user", "my_pass");
```

I use Propel 1.6.7 (using Phing), the array that is using for connection on Propel is:

```
return array (
            'datasources' => 
            array (
                'datasource' => 
                array (
                    'adapter' => 'informix', //'mysql','postgres'
                    'connection' => 
                    array (
                        'dsn' => 'informix:host=host.domain.com;service=9800;database=my_db;'
                        'user' => 'user',
                        'password' => 'password',
                    ),
                ),
                'default' => 'datasource',
            ),
            'generator_version' => '1.6.7',
            'classmap' => include('dir/to/classmap-conf.php')
        );
```

If is necessary I can use Propel 1.7 or Propel 2.0, any that it can to connect with Informix (It may be necessary to use the PDO library,).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Propel Documentation](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/01-installation.html#prerequisites), the only supported Databases are:

- MS SQL Server
- MySQL
- Oracle
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite